# How to copy in the paragraph style in python docx module

Tags: python, styles, python-docx

I have a question regarding how to correctly copy a paragraph style in docx.

What I am trying to do here, is I have a little project where I'm trying to automate some question making.

The task, is to simply substitute the questions and choices, while preserving the numbering styles (all under standard word docx numbering format).

Following is a picture for your information.

[image]

This word file is loaded with docx as sample

```
sample = docx.Document('C:/Users/User/Desktop/ProblemMaker/sample.docx')
```

when I locate the respective location, problem one and its five options pertains to paragraph 20 to 25

I've been reading the docx documentation (https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html) and my initial thought was as follows:

```
for i in range(20,26):
    templ.add_paragraph(sample.paragraphs[i].text).style = sample.paragraphs[i].style
```

which computed without error, but once I saved the result and viewed the output on the word program, the numberings were all gone but indented in by a single tab.

Can anyone share some insights, or point me in the right direction with this?

Thank you very much in advance!